# DropDown Nav that disappears onclick

Tags: html, css, navbar, dropdown, nav

I'm trying to have my nav to dropdown on click, and that goes up (disappears) also on click. Mainly for the phone version, because I'm gonna use hover for the pc version. I tried using focus and active and it doesn't work. I'm not really wanting to try javascript. I'm new to css, but I'll appreciate you comments.

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #000;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: If the answer helps please mark it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with focus on the button. You have to add media queries to adjust when and what should work but this is the line you do for open. The + indicates that "the item next to me". I have commented out the hover for demo.

```
.dropbtn:focus + .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #000;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/*.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}*/

.dropbtn:focus + .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```